# Multiplying a range with cell

Tags: excel, vba

1) How can I multiply a range with a another cell that contains a value and place the new values in the column beside?

2) What is the use of Set rng as Range? How is this different from Dim rng as range?

3) I need to click the " keyboard button twice before " appears and it appears as "". How do I fix this problem such that " will appear upon clicking the keyboard button once?

Here are my codes.

```
Sub try()

Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

x = Range("A1:A5").Value

Range("B1:B5").Value = x * cells ( 1 , "E")

End Sub()
```

I get a

> run time error 13; type mismatch

I tried this

```
Sub try()

Dim rng as range
Set rng as Range

rng = Range("A1:A5").Value

Range("B1:B5").Value = rng * cells( 1 , "E")
End Sub()
```

I get a syntax error for the line `Set rng as Range`

If I remove this line, I get a error of

> error 91, Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Please try to limit to one question per page, or at least related questions.

Comment: You can't assign multple ranges to an integer variable. You don't need VBA for this anyway.

Comment: as for the "range" thing, you might need `Set rng = Range("A1:A5")`

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, while you don't need VBA, you could do this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub try()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lrow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lrow)
        x = .Cells(1, "E").Value
    End With

    For Each cel In rng
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel.Value * x
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
Sub try()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B1:B5").Value = .Evaluate("=A1:A5 * $E$1")
    End With
End Sub
```

2) `Set Range As Range` isn't valid syntax, so it's unclear what you're asking here

3) Sounds like your keyboard is broken?